# Link in ChartJS tooltip not clickable

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, chart.js, tooltip

I've added an `<a>` tag to my custom tooltip, but when I click on it it doesn't redirect to the href.

I copied the custom tooltip exactly from [these docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#external-custom-tooltips). I'll also paste the code below for ease.

Then, I added the following innerHTML:

```
var tableRoot = tooltipEl.querySelector("table");
    tableRoot.innerHTML = innerHtml + '<a href="www.google.com">Click Here</a>';
```

However, the link isn't clickable - it doesn't even trigger `cursor: pointer` like a normal `<a>` tag.

The full custom tooltip code:

```
custom: function(tooltipModel) {
            // Tooltip Element
            var tooltipEl = document.getElementById('chartjs-tooltip');

            // Create element on first render
            if (!tooltipEl) {
                tooltipEl = document.createElement('div');
                tooltipEl.id = 'chartjs-tooltip';
                tooltipEl.innerHTML = '<table></table>';
                document.body.appendChild(tooltipEl);
            }

            // Hide if no tooltip
            if (tooltipModel.opacity === 0) {
                tooltipEl.style.opacity = 0;
                return;
            }

            // Set caret Position
            tooltipEl.classList.remove('above', 'below', 'no-transform');
            if (tooltipModel.yAlign) {
                tooltipEl.classList.add(tooltipModel.yAlign);
            } else {
                tooltipEl.classList.add('no-transform');
            }

            function getBody(bodyItem) {
                return bodyItem.lines;
            }

            // Set Text
            if (tooltipModel.body) {
                var titleLines = tooltipModel.title || [];
                var bodyLines = tooltipModel.body.map(getBody);

                var innerHtml = '<thead>';

                titleLines.forEach(function(title) {
                    innerHtml += '<tr><th>' + title + '</th></tr>';
                });
                innerHtml += '</thead><tbody>';

                bodyLines.forEach(function(body, i) {
                    var colors = tooltipModel.labelColors[i];
                    var style = 'background:' + colors.backgroundColor;
                    style += '; border-color:' + colors.borderColor;
                    style += '; border-width: 2px';
                    var span = '<span style="' + style + '"></span>';
                    innerHtml += '<tr><td>' + span + body + '</td></tr>';
                });
                innerHtml += '</tbody>';

                var tableRoot = tooltipEl.querySelector('table');
                tableRoot.innerHTML = innerHtml;
            }

            // `this` will be the overall tooltip
            var position = this._chart.canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

            // Display, position, and set styles for font
            tooltipEl.style.opacity = 1;
            tooltipEl.style.position = 'absolute';
            tooltipEl.style.left = position.left + window.pageXOffset + tooltipModel.caretX + 'px';
            tooltipEl.style.top = position.top + window.pageYOffset + tooltipModel.caretY + 'px';
            tooltipEl.style.fontFamily = tooltipModel._bodyFontFamily;
            tooltipEl.style.fontSize = tooltipModel.bodyFontSize + 'px';
            tooltipEl.style.fontStyle = tooltipModel._bodyFontStyle;
            tooltipEl.style.padding = tooltipModel.yPadding + 'px ' + tooltipModel.xPadding + 'px';
            tooltipEl.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

I've faced the very problem myself, so I tried to remove this line:

```
tooltipEl.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
```

but it didn't work as expected - every time I hovered over the tooltip it disappeared.

Then, I tried this:

1. Keep the line above just as it is;
2. Modify `events` prop of the `options`. (See [docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/interactions.html#events)).
   By doing this, you actually remove 'mouseout' event from the default config.

   ```
   const options = {
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            events: ['mousemove', 'click', 'touchstart', 'touchmove'],
            plugins: {
                tooltip: {
                    enabled: false,
                    external: externalTooltipHandler
                },
                legend: {
                    display: false
                }
            },
        }
   ```
3. Then, remove pointer-events from the sole clickable element of the tooltip. In my case, it is `li` element. I did this with CSS. `li { pointer-events: auto; }`

When 1-3 steps are completed, the external tooltip is supposed to behave as expected AND the link elements contained in that tooltip should be clickable.

Answer (score 2):

Remove

```
        tooltipEl.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
```

and any of theese from CSS

```
        pointer-events: none;
```